# Copying Joomla Menu Items and keeping Module assignements

Tags: module, cms, menu

Currently in Joomla 3.2, selecting "Save as copy" on a menu item copies the details but not the module assignments into a new menu item. (I believe module assignments were copied in Joomla 2.5)

Is there a way to copy menu items in Joomla 3.2 while also copying module assignments?

Comment: I realized I completely misread your post. Like completely way off. I deleted my answer. I was thinking you were copying modules, you're copying menu items. This may actually be considered a "bug" to be honest. I'd look for a way to submit that as a feature request to be put back in a future version.

Comment: Would it worked if you created a new menu item and chose the menu type as Menu item Alias? You would have to do this for each menu item you wanted to 'copy'.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that was an option. I just played around with it but, the module assignments weren't copied

Comment: @BrianPeat thanks, I've opened #33647 in the bug tracker.

Comment: Interesting, this doesn't happen in a clean install of Joomla 3.2.2

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that as modules are assigned to a menu item id and saving a menu item as new will give it a new menu Id which no modules are assigned to.

Moving an item will keep its id but not copying.

Answer (score 3):

I needed exactly the same thing so I made a plugin that makes Save as copy work that way. You can find it here: https://github.com/alexxandar/copy-module-assignments

Comment: I would like to test it, but install gives me an error "Unable to find install package". I have tried on both J3.4.8 on PHP5.6 and J3.5.0-rc4 on PHP7. How should I proceed?

Comment: Just copy the files to Joomla install, go to Extension Manager and then to Discover option. I haven't packed so that it can be installed the standard way. Honestly it was late and I was tired :)

Soon I will repack the files so that you can install regular way. Thanks

Comment: Hvala druze, radi... Thanx bro, it's working... Nice one!